# Ruby iterate through JSON response and return values

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, hash

I am trying to iterate through JSON and I keep falling foul of the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

What I want to do is iterate through my response and based my rules return a segment of data. My response is as follows:

```
data = JSON.parse(response)

data = (whats below)

{
        “summary”: {
          “Id”: 5452,
          “IdOutcome”: "Scored",
          “Results”: [
            {
              “test”: "car",
              “value”: 10.0,
              “num”: 0
            },
            {
              “test”: "carz",
              “value”: 0.0,
              “num”: 0
            },
            {
              “test”: "bars",
              “value”: 10.0,
              “num”: 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

So in the example response above I want to iterate through "Results" and return back either "test" or heck even all of the block for the highest num value. So in the example below I would be returned

```
"bars",
10.0,
1
```

or just

```
"bars"
```

SO essentially I just need to iterate through the returned array data.

Comment: We'd like to see your effort toward solving this. Without that it looks like you haven't written anything and want us to do it, which is off-topic for SO. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `Enumerable#max_by`:

```
max_result = data["summary"]["Results"].max_by {|r| r["num"] }
# => { "test" => "bars",
#      "value" => 10.0,
#      "num" => 1
#    }

max_result["test"]
# => "bars"
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `54a52` is not valid. You probably need to ecapsulate it in quotations `"54a52"`. If you change that, it will parse the string correctly.

```
JSON.parse('{"summary":{"Id":"54a52","IdOutcome":"Scored","Results":[{"test":"car","value":10.0,"num":0},{"test":"carz","value":0.0,"num":0},{"test":"bars","value":10.0,"num":1}]}}')
=> {"summary"=>{"Id"=>"54a52", "IdOutcome"=>"Scored", "Results"=>[{"test"=>"car", "value"=>10.0, "num"=>0}, {"test"=>"carz", "value"=>0.0, "num"=>0}, {"test"=>"bars", "value"=>10.0, "num"=>1}]}}
```

Comment: apologies that was my mistake when I was fudging the response data. I can successfully parse but what I want to do is now pull specific values out of the parsed response